# как сделать так что бы в массив добавлялось значение через запятую, а не обновляло старое?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

как сделать так что бы в массив добавлялось значение через запятую, а не обновляло старое ?

```
let p = [];

let setId = 'id'
const[add ,setAdd] = React.useState(0)

function opa() {
    setAdd(add + 1)
    p.push(setId+add);
  console.log(p)
};
```

Comment: Нужно больше конкретики, чего вы хотите.

Comment: что бы когда я нажимал на функцию "opa" к "add " прибавлялось число + 1 что бы были новые idN
но выходит что массив равен [id1} после того как я еще раз нажму он будет [id2] и так далее, а надо что бы было вот так [id1] => [id1, id2] и так далее

Comment: Текущее поведение - логичное. Когда вы изменяете состояние у `add`, у вас происходит перерендер компонента, ир есит `p` инициируется заново. Вам для нее нужно свой стейт.

Comment: все да. я уже разобрался